# Creating columns in table by using records of another table

Tags: dynamic-columns

I want to create table B in database, table B will contain columns same as the records of particular column in Table A. Means I have to create Table B with columns same as records in Table A. How to do this? Suggestions please? [This is the desired table from which i want to copy records of one column and add to another table as columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8LWE.jpg)

Comment: Post some sample data and the desired results.  Explain what you have already tried and  where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: I have tried to make table dynamically using query $sql = "CREATE TABLE `$course`  AS (SELECT * FROM criteria WHERE course='$course')"; but this will result same columns copied to another table. I need to copy records of one column from single table to create columns in another table dynamically